# BLAKE2 input parameters

Tags: c, hash, cryptography

Being a newbie, I was reading papers on the recent crop of hash functions and [BLAKE2](https://blake2.net/) intrigued me. Then I wanted to play around with the "blake2s" code in the code package.

If I were to implement a simple string hasher, I could understand that there are built-in variables for a key and salt.

But I couldn't figure out how to provide a string or file as input and collect the hash as input. Which variable(s) are responsible for the message and the digest?

Maybe I'm doing things wrong but the following doesn't print any output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "blake2s.h"
#include "blake2s.c"

#define SIZE 1024

int main(){
    unsigned char *str, *hash;
    str = malloc(SIZE * sizeof *str);
    hash = malloc(32 * sizeof *str);
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    int a = blake2s(hash, str, NULL, 32, 1024, 0);
    if(a)
        printf("%s", hash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops. If I were to salt it now then would I need to pipe the salts from /dev/(u)random ?

Comment: I don't see much point in using the salt feature, and AFAIK the reference implementation doesn't expose it. The third parameter is the key and what you want to use as key depends on what you're doing. It's pretty much the same thing as the key for HMAC or HKDF.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", str)` only reads up to the first white space (blank, tab, newline).   It is generally a good idea to print the data you read so that you know the program got what you think it got.  If you type words to the program, only the first word will be hashed.  Or, worse, if the 1024 parameter to `blake2s()` says "there are 1024 bytes of data to hash", then you are passing indeterminate data to the function because `malloc()` is not obliged to set the allocated memory to any specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has two issues that directly relate to printing the hash:

1. Success is indicated by returning `0`. So your `if` needs to be replaced by something like

   ```
   if(a==0)
        printf("%s", hashStr);
   else
        printf("error %d", a);
   ```
2. The hash is raw binary and can even contain `\0` bytes. You should apply hex or Base64 encoding before printing it.

And a few other bugs and stylistic issues:

1. You probably want to replace the 1024 passed to the hasher by `strlen(str)`, so it only hashes the actual string.
2. Your program suffers from a buffer overflow if the user enters more than 1024 bytes. No big issue in a test program, but something you should fix in a proper implementation since it'd be a security hole.
3. `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition