# Blake2b hash native C library usage

Tags: c++, c, hash

I am trying to use the native C library in my project (this one https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2) but it's not clear to me how to use it: it seems to be possible to use a step-by-step version (blake2b_init, blake2b_update and blake2b_final) and simpler one (blake2b).

Here (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7693#appendix-A) I found a complete explanation about it and an example of use (page 26) in which they simply do this (I don't want to use the key too):

```
blake2b(md, outlen, NULL, 0, in, inlen);
```

One of my problems is that in the library source code (blake2.h) I find a "Simple API" that is the following

```
int blake2b( void *out, size_t outlen, const void *in, size_t inlen, const void *key, size_t keylen );
```

So the syntax is different: the input and key positions are swapped.

Furthermore, in a previous question ([BLAKE2 input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813502/blake2-input-parameters)) it's said that the result should be checked (and the correct one is when it is 0). I know that here they use blake2s but the meaning of the result should be the same also for blake2b.

My main problem is that I tried both usages but the result is always -1. So, I think I am not using the library correctly.

Here is my code.

```
const char* pInput = "test text";
char* pOutput = new char[128];
int nRes = blake2b(pOutput, 128, pInput, strlen(pInput), NULL, 0);
```

and

```
const char* pInput = "test text";
char* pOutput = new char[128];
int nRes = blake2b(pOutput, 128, NULL, 0, pInput, strlen(pInput));
```

The result is always -1 and in the output I haven't my hash.

Does anyone have ever use this library and/or have an updated documentation about it that shows the correct usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking `blake2b()` to produce 128 bytes of output, while the maximum it can produce is only 32 bytes. There's an `enum` for that in the header file: `BLAKE2B_OUTBYTES`. So write:

```
const char *pInput = "test text";
char *pOutput = new char[BLAKE2B_OUTBYTES];
int nRes = blake2b(pOutput, BLAKE2B_OUTBYTES, pInput, strlen(pInput), NULL, 0);
```